# Remove Linkage in the other Scenes?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, linkage, scene

I wanted to have a class linkage of my MovieCip in the first scene.
But when i go to second Scene, i don't want anymore this linkage.

Answer (score 0):

Change the MC to a Graphic on the stage, if that makes sense. If not, you'll need to make a copy in the Library without the linkage.